# Debug JavaScript anonymous block in VSCode in non node runtime

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have an application that has a javascript runtime and it expects some snippets to run inside it. I'm trying to debug and set breakpoints but I'm not being able to. For reference it uses deno under the hood.

I can configure this app to auto break and this is the only way I can manage to debug it (because I can go line by line until the point I want to check). I believe the issue is with the maps but I have no idea how to make it map the anonymous code being executed with the script I have.

This is a sample script that I run.

```js
async (workflow_id, task_id, config, input) => {
    console.log(input);
    console.log(config);
    console.log(task_id);
    console.log(workflow_id);
    return {
        "ok": {
            "message": `hello ${input.name}`
        }
    };
}
```

An anonymous block like this is generated and executed:

```js
Deno.core.ops();
(async function(){
    let input = {"name":"Augusto"};
    let config = null;
    let func = async (workflow_id, task_id, config, input) => { // -------> here my code is appended
        console.log(input);
        console.log(config);
        console.log(task_id);
        console.log(workflow_id);
        return {
            "ok": {
                "message": `hello ${input.name}`
            }
        };
    };
    let result = await func(0, 0, config, input);
    let message = {
        workflow_id: 0,
        task_id: 0,
        output: result
    };
    console.log(message);
})();
```

When I go line by line eventually I can reach the anonymous code generated by my application, but the problem is that vscode doesn't link it to the script in my project, and therefore, doesn't recognise any breakpoints I set in it.

Is there a way to make vscode recognise this anonymous function and map it to my local script file?

Here's how I configure the `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Debug WM Script",
        "type": "pwa-node",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/debugger",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "-f",
          "./test.json",
          "-s",
          "./test.js"   // ------------> this is my local script file I wanted to debug
        ],
        "attachSimplePort": 9229,
        "outputCapture": "std",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        ],
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/*.js"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

You can see in the image bellow how vscode shows my anonymous code.

[image: vscode preview]

Comment: You can debug directly in the browser as well - this may work better for anon functions.

Comment: This anonymous code block is generated by you? Can you change the code inside?

Comment: @Anton yes. Part of it is a file on my `workspaceFolder` and the other part is generated at runtime by an application I have (which I also have the access to change)

Comment: If you can control the code, then just add `debugger;` in the place you want to break executing the script. The browser will stop and open debugger. Link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp

Comment: @Anton you're right that it stops where I want and this helps a lot already, but it still doesn't map to my local source file